# Is serving Google No Captcha reCaptcha's api.js locally preventing correct behavior?

Tags: javascript, google-api, captcha, recaptcha

I recently updated my recaptcha implementation to google's new version. My understanding is that some reasonable fraction of users should see captchas that are not standard distorted text / read the address photos.

The captchas work correctly in a sense of serving and giving correct responses to user input, but on every single usage of the widget I am asked for the answer to a distorted text question, just like the old reCaptcha.

My question is this: is this the result of misconfiguration / misimplementation on my part, and, if so, how can I fix this?

My hypothesis at the moment is that this is an effect of me serving the gateway api.js file from my own server instead of from google directly...if that is a likely culprit, how is it affecting the captcha operation?

Thanks folks!

Comment: Can you provide use the client side part of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, the answer was yes. api.js has a magic url in it that changes periodically, so it does need to be either updated very frequently or served from google's servers.